# Override method GET to DELETE in nodeJS using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, supposed i have this link in my ejs file :

```
<a href="/user/12">Delete</a>
```

And in my route file, i have delete code like following :

```
router.delete( '/user/:id', function ( req, res ) {
   // delete operation stuff
});
```

So my question is, how i can override `GET` request from link into `DELETE` method to ensure my `router.delete` route able to handle it. Right now, its only detect the request as a `GET`. I'm using this [Method Override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) module to handle it, But seems like all of examples were using form element, not the anchor way. Anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyway, right now here is the solutions i used to override `GET` request by using `middleware` before application request was made, so far for the link i change the `href` to look like this :

```
<a href="/user/12?_method=DELETE" >Delete</a>
```

And in route :

```
router.use( function( req, res, next ) {
    // this middleware will call for each requested
    // and we checked for the requested query properties
    // if _method was existed
    // then we know, clients need to call DELETE request instead
    if ( req.query._method == 'DELETE' ) {
        // change the original METHOD
        // into DELETE method
        req.method = 'DELETE';
        // and set requested url to /user/12
        req.url = req.path;
    }       
    next(); 
});
```

Finally, the requested path will match this route :

```
router.delete( '/user/:id', function ( req, res ) {
  // delete operation stuff
});
```

Anyone who encountered this problems may try it out and if anyone who facing this problems and able to solved it with great solutions, please let me know. Happy codding!

Comment: You sir have made my morning a little less frustrating. Thanks!